# Generate a csv file partly based on user input with python

Tags: python, csv

i need to create a .csv file with six rows partly based on a users input partly based on fixed parameters. While the fixed parameters aren't an issue, three of the variables are.

1. I need to add a (non repeating) random number in range from 1 to 6 in every row of the file. I came up with the idea to use np.random.choice to create those numbers and add with every loop the first, second, third […] element to the row, but it won't work.
2. The user should be able to chose wether two variables (e. g. X or Y) repeat themself in a row or not. For example: If the user input is '2', two of 6 rows have to contain X,X or Y,Y, if the input is 0 none of the rows should contain X,X or Y,Y. Truth be told, i have no idea how to code stuff like that.

Here is my code so far.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

t_delay = input("xxx:")
t_target = input("xxx:")
rndTrial = np.random.choice(6, 6, replace=False) # Problem 1
X_Y = input("xxx:") # Problem 2

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline = '') as my_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    writer.writerow(['Head1', 'Head2', 'Head...'])

    for lazy in range(0, 6):
        writer.writerow([60, 12 , t_delay, t_target, X, Y, rndTrial]
```

If the user chose to have 3 rows with the same (X or Y) variables,  the desired .csv file should look like this:

```
fixed, fixed, user_input, user_input, problem2, problem2, random_number
60,12,t_delay,t_target,X,X,1
60,12,t_delay,t_target,X,Y,2
60,12,t_delay,t_target,Y,X,3
60,12,t_delay,t_target,X,X,4
60,12,t_delay,t_target,Y,Y,5
60,12,t_delay,t_target,X,Y,6
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your lists with what you need in each of them, without worrying about the order.  Then use `random.shuffle` on them.

```
from random import shuffle, random

list1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]   # integers 1 to 6, without repeating
shuffle(list1)

nb_same = 3         # this can come from user input, must be in 0..6
list2 = []
for i in range(nb_same):
  list2.append( 'X,X' if random() < 0.5 else 'Y,Y' )
while len(list2) < 6:
  list2.append( 'X,Y' if random() < 0.5 else 'Y,X' )
shuffle(list2)
```

You can print the two variables `list1` and  `list2` to verify they fulfill the requested parameters.

I assumed 50%-50% when choosing either similar or different pairs.

I did not write shorter code (on purpose) for easier understanding.

From there, you only have to print your csv.

Comment: Thank you Sci Prog. One last question: How do I select the first, second, third [...] list elements of list1 and list2 and add it to the loop "for lazy in range(0, 6)"? What I have in mind: First loop -> take first list element of list1 and list 2 and add it to the row -> second loop -> take second [...]. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  With `for i in range(0,6):` you can use the loop variable as an index for `list1` and `list2`, this will not remove the element from the array.  If you want to take the first element of a list, and remove it from the list, you can use the `.pop(0)` method (see python documentation) on both `list1` and `list2`.